# Subquery vs Join and where - which one is faster?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have two sql's which gives me same results:

Query 1:

```
SELECT
u.*, COUNT(po.order_id) products_count
FROM (SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE o.date >= (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) o
LEFT JOIN products_orders po ON po.order_id=o.id
JOIN users u ON u.id=o.user_id
GROUP BY po.order_id
```

and Query 2:

```
SELECT
u.*, o.id order_id, COUNT(po.order_id) products_count
FROM users u
JOIN orders o ON o.user_id=u.id
LEFT JOIN products_orders po ON po.order_id=o.id
WHERE o.date >= (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY po.order_id
```

I wonder.. which one should be faster?
Query Explains shows them to be equals... What do you think guys?
[image: Query 1]
[image: Query 2]

Comment: if the explain plan is the same, then the performance should be the same.  keep in mind Cost based optimizers are allowed to "Fiddle" with your SQL to get the best possible result (at least what it thinks is best in terms of correctness and performance)

Comment: Please don't cross-post:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179878/subquery-vs-join-and-where-which-one-is-faster

Comment: Voted for deleting

Answer (score 2):

Normally JOINs are more efficient than subqueries and is reflected within an `EXPLAIN` output. This is because using a subquery requires a virtual table to be made on the fly, and then query with that table. Using a JOIN on an existing table skips this step and allows the optimizer to take advantage of having knowledge of this table in the form of indexes or cached data.

The likely reason why your EXPLAINs are equal here is because of how simple your subquery is. Since you are just doing a select all with a where condition, the optimizer can typically notice this and parse the subquery and JOIN on the table and apply the WHERE later on. So, the optimizer is effectively rewriting your subquery version as your JOIN version, before executing.

Answer (score 0):

the query are not exactly the same you select different columns
you could add the where condition directly on the on clause avoiding where
Should be faster the query withou subselect  .. because don't need  a temporary table for store the result of subquery

```
  SELECT
      u.*
      , o.id order_id
      , COUNT(po.order_id) products_count
  FROM users u
  INNER JOIN orders o ON o.user_id=u.id   
          and o.date >= (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  LEFT JOIN products_orders po ON po.order_id=o.id 
  GROUP BY po.order_id
```

check avoiding where and using on